# How to handle unexpected data length in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How do I handle a column with unexpected data length in Azure synapse like we have in SQL server VARCHAR(MAX) what data type should I use in synapse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In synapse you cannot have varchar(max) while you are using
{
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE Ip put
Therefore we need to use heap instead of clusted columnstore index
{
| HEAP
}}

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.